# Modifying the conditions of all breakpoints in Visual Studio 2015+

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I am debugging a large application, with multiple threads going through the parts I am interested in.  I would like to use breakpoints to follow just one of these threads.

In order to do this I am using the breakpoint Filter condition, ThreadId=#.  However when stopping and starting the solution, the ThreadId of the thread I would like to follow changes.  I currently need to change all of my breakpoint conditions manually by right clicking them in the Breakpoint window, selecting Settings, then changing the ThreadId condition to point to the right thread.

Is there a way to automate this process?

**EDIT: For my application, the best way to resolve this was to set Conditional breakpoints monitoring a particular variable which was consistent in the thread I wanted to follow, rather than filtering by thread ID.**

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to change the Filter condition breakpoint automatically, it would have a limitation for it.

We could set it using two ways:

(1)Using the breakpoint windows as yours.

(2) Hover over the breakpoint to bring up the breakpoint’s toolbar and click the “Settings…” icon.

[image]